# How to not stop nohup and get output files

Tags: python, linux, docker, nvidia, nohup

I’m new to working on Linux. I apologize if this is a dumb question. Despite searching for more than a week, I was not able to derive a clear answer to my question.

I’m running a very long Python program on Nvidia CPUs. The output is several csv files. It takes long to compute the output, so I use `nohup` to be able to exit the process.

Let’s say `main.py` file is this

```
import numpy as p
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    
    a = np.arange(1,1000)
    data = a*2

    filename = ‘results.csv’

    output = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [“Output”])
    output.to_csv(filename)
```

The calculations for `data` is more complicated, of course. I build a docker container, and run this program inside this container. When I use `python main.py` for a smaller-sized example, there is no problem. It writes the csv files.

My question is this:

1. When I do `nohup python main.py &`, I check what’s going on with `tail -f nohup.out` in the docker container, I get what it is doing at that time but I cannot exit it and let the execution run its course. It just stops there. How can I exit safely from the screen that comes with `tail -f nohup.out`?
2. I tried not checking the condition of the code and letting the code continue for two days, then I returned. The output of `tail -f nohup.out` indicated that the execution finished but csv files were nowhere to be seen. It is somehow bundled up inside `nohup.out` or does it indicate something else is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to run this setup in a Docker container:

1. A Docker container runs only one process, as a foreground process; when that process exits the container completes.  That process is almost always the script or server you're trying to run and not an interactive shell.  But;
2. It's possible to use Docker constructs to run the container itself in the background, and collect its logs while it's running or after it completes.

A typical Dockerfile for a Python program like this might look like:

```sh
FROM python:3.10

# Create and use some directory; it can be anything, but do
# create _some_ directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Install Python dependencies as a separate step.  Doing this first
# saves time if you repeat `docker build` without changing the
# requirements list.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy in the rest of the application.
COPY . .

# Set the main container command to be the script.
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

The script should be executable (`chmod +x main.py` on your host) and begin with a "shebang" line (`#!/usr/bin/env python3`) so the system knows where to find the interpreter.

You will hear recommendations to use both `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` for the final line.  It doesn't matter much to your immediate question.  I prefer `CMD` for two reasons: it's easier to launch an alternate command to debug your container (`docker run --rm your-image ls -l` vs. `docker run --rm --entrypoint ls your-image -l`), and there's a very useful pattern of using `ENTRYPOINT` to do some initial setup (creating environment variables dynamically, running database migrations, ...) and then launching `CMD`.

Having built the image, you can use the [`docker run -d`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#detached--d) option to launch it in the background, and then run [`docker logs`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/) to see what comes out of it.

```sh
# Build the image.
docker build -t long-python-program .

# Run it, in the background.
docker run -d --name run1 long-python-program

# Review its logs.
docker logs run1
```

---

If you're running this to produce files that need to be read back from the host, you need to mount a host directory into your container at the time you start it.  You need to make a couple of changes to do this successfully.

In your code, you need to write the results somewhere different than your application code.  You can't mount a host directory over the `/app` directory since it will hide the code you're actually trying to run.

```py
data_dir = os.getenv('DATA_DIR', 'data')
filename = os.path.join(data_dir, 'results.csv')
```

Optionally, in your Dockerfile, create this directory and set a pointer to it.  Since my sample code gets its location from an environment variable you can again use any path you want.

```sh
# Create the data directory.
RUN mkdir /data
ENV DATA_DIR=/data
```

When you launch the container, the [`docker run -v`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems) option mounts filesystems into the container.  For this sort of output file you're looking for a [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) that directly attaches a host directory to the container.

```sh
docker run -d --name run2 \
  -v "$PWD/results:/data" \
  long-python-program
```

In this example so far we haven't set the `USER` of the program, and it will run as root.  You can change the Dockerfile to set up an alternate `USER` (which is good practice); you do not need to `chown` anything except the `data` directory to be owned by that user (leaving your code owned by root and not world-writeable is also good practice).  If you do this, *when you launch the container* (on native Linux) you need to provide the host numeric user ID that can write to the host directory; you do not need to make other changes in the Dockerfile.

```sh
docker run -d --name run2 \
  -u $(id -u) \
  -v "$PWD/results:/data" \
  long-python-program
```

Answer (score 0):

1- Container is a foreground process. Use `CMD` or `Entrypoint` in `Dockerfile`.

2- Map volume in docker to linux directory's.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).